# how to create a log to track excel refresh

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have connected excel to MySQL database using PHP. Right now, my users can refresh the excel spread sheet to  get the current data from MySQL database. I used web query instead of ODBC.

But, I want to create a log file in MySQL database to track when, who, and what cell/value has been refreshed .

I tried to use triggers, however, it only tracks table changes within MySQL database, not excel.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a script on my php file to insert all the information I want to include in the log such as user,and refresh time. It works now.